# C++ Passing pointers through class functions from main()

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I know pointers is something that is discussed a lot. I have done a LOT of research to try and solve this problem, however everything is leading me to a dead end.

I have an assignment that is asking me to create a class that records a single test score. If the test score has already been recorded and a new score is higher, override it. If it has been recorded and the new score is lower, do nothing. If it hasn't been recorded, record it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//  CIS 235 exercise 7

#include <iostream>


using namespace::std;

//   declare a class for recording a test score
//   the data will be pointer to an integer, rather than an integer
//
//   - this exercise is designed to show how to work with pointer memory
//   - of course, we would NOT normally use a pointer for just an integer
//   - to illustrate the concepts, but keep the implementation simple,
//             integer data was used.  The general case would be object data,
//             not integer data

class testScore
{
   public:
   //  declare a default constructor - the pointer should be set to NULL
   testScore();
   //  declare a function that returns a bool, indicating if the test has been taken
   bool hasTestTaken();
   //  declare a function to record the test score, the parameter will be an integer
   //  use the following rules
   //  -  if no test has been taken, allocate memory and record the score
   //  -  if a test has been taken and the parameter is less than or equal to
   //         the score, do nothing
   //  -  if the test has been taken and the parameter is  higher than the score,
   //         - release the old memory
   //         - allocate new memory
   //         - record the score
   void recordScore(int *myScore);
   //   declare a function to print the score to an ostream parameter
   //   if the test has not been taken, send an appropriate message to the ostream
   //         otherwise print the score
   void printScore(ostream &out);
   //   declare the destructor
   //   be CAREFUL, you will need an if statement in your destructor
   ~testScore();

   private:
   //  declare the data needed to implement the class
   bool testTaken;
   int *score;
 };

//  write the 5 member functions

testScore::testScore() : score(NULL)
{
//  declare a default constructor - the pointer should be set to NULL
}

bool testScore::hasTestTaken()
{
   //  declare a function that returns a bool, indicating if the test has been taken
   return testTaken;
}

void testScore::recordScore(int *myScore)
{
   if(testTaken == false)
   {
                testTaken = true;
                *score = *myScore;
   }
   else if(testTaken == true && *myScore > *score)
   {
                score = NULL;
                delete score;
                score = new int;
                *score = *myScore;
   }

}

void testScore::printScore(ostream& out)
{
      //   declare a function to print the score to an ostream parameter
   //   if the test has not been taken, send an appropriate message to the ostream
   //         otherwise print the score
     if(testTaken)
     {
                  out << *score << endl;
     }
     else
         out << "The test has not been taken!" << endl;
}

testScore::~testScore()
{
   //   declare the destructor
   //   be CAREFUL, you will need an if statement in your destructor
   if(score != NULL)
   {
             score = NULL;
             delete score;
   }
   else
       delete score;

}

//  test the class member functions
//    - declare an object, but do NOT record a score for the object

//    - declare a second object and record the scores of 83, 78, 92
//       use appropriate member print functions to verify your code
//int abc = 83;
int abc = 0;
int main()
{
//    int abc = 0;
//    int * score2;
//    myTestScore = new int;
//    *myTestScore = 83;

    testScore firstScore;
    firstScore.printScore(cout);

    testScore secondScore;
//    secondScore.recordScore(&abc);
      secondScore.recordScore(&abc);
//    secondScore.printScore(cout);
//    *myTestScore = 78;
//    secondScore.recordScore(myTestScore);
//    secondScore.printScore(cout);
//    *myTestScore = 92;
//    secondScore.recordScore(myTestScore);
//    secondScore.printScore(cout);


   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Pointers is something rather new to me...I have looked them up, and looked them up, and looked them up some more but I seem to ALWAYS get them wrong.

Knowing that, I'm aware that my recordScore function is probably doing something very wrong, but I don't know what.

My main problem right now, is that the firstScore is running fine (yay! I got something right...maybe) however, the secondScore won't record a score. I have tried a few different ways.

1. I put the int abc = 0; above int main()

   - Compiles and runs fine when I call recordScore
   - Compiles and crashes when I call printScore

     - Output shows: This test has been taken! Press any key to continue... (crashes)
2. I put the int abc = 0; inside the int main() but before anything else

   - Crashes when I call recordScore before anything gets outputted to console

This also crashes if my int main() looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int abc = 0;

    testScore firstScore;
    firstScore.printScore(cout);


   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

And I have no idea why T.T

I have also tried:

Declaring

```
int *myTestScore;
myTestScore = new int;
*myTestScore = 83;
```

inside main() but before anything else, and passing myTestScore to recordScore via:

```
&myTestScore
```

Compile error: no matching function for call to 'testScore::recordScore(int**);
on the secondScore.recordScore line.

```
*myTestScore
```

Compile error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
on the secondScore.recordScore line.

```
myTestScore
```

No compile error, crashes when it runs before anything is output to console

I have tried declaring:

```
int *myTestScore = 83;
```

inside of int main() before anything else
Compile error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
on the int *myTestScore = 83 line.

I have also tried various methods of changing the recordScore to using &'s and *'s and neither and varying combinations of both.

I am now out of ideas of things to try, and even after researching I can't come up with anything. I have tried to ask my professor (for a week now, it's on online course), calling her, e-mailing her, but she has not answered any of the questions I have or even requests for a meeting.

I feel there is something simple I am not grasping here, and I really appreciate any help anyone can give me to figure this problem out.

Thank you so much for your time.

---

Changes:

```
testScore::testScore() : score(NULL), testTaken(false) // didnt change because instructor instructions, but did move testTaken up cause that is where it should be
{
    //  declare a default constructor - the pointer should be set to NULL
}

void testScore::recordScore(int myScore)
{
   if(testTaken == false)
   {
                testTaken = true;
                score = &myScore;
                cout << *score << endl; //this prints correctly, 0
   }
   else if(testTaken == true && myScore > *score)
   {
                //removed the score = NULL to avoid a memory leak (I think this is correct now?)
                delete score;
                score = new int;
                score = &myScore;
   }

}

void testScore::printScore(ostream& out)//no changes, just easier to access to you dont have to keep scrolling up
{
      //   declare a function to print the score to an ostream parameter
   //   if the test has not been taken, send an appropriate message to the ostream
   //         otherwise print the score
     if(testTaken)
     {
                  out << *score << endl; //outputs incorrect 4469696
     }
     else
         out << "The test has not been taken!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int abc = 0;

    testScore firstScore;
    firstScore.printScore(cout);

    testScore secondScore;
    secondScore.recordScore(abc);
    secondScore.printScore(cout);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Outputs:
This test has not been taken!
0
4469696
Press any key to continue...

---

Final working product:

```
//  CIS 235 exercise 7

#include <iostream>


using namespace::std;

//   declare a class for recording a test score
//   the data will be pointer to an integer, rather than an integer
//
//   - this exercise is designed to show how to work with pointer memory
//   - of course, we would NOT normally use a pointer for just an integer
//   - to illustrate the concepts, but keep the implementation simple,
//             integer data was used.  The general case would be object data,
//             not integer data

class testScore
{
   public:
   //  declare a default constructor - the pointer should be set to NULL
   testScore();
   //  declare a function that returns a bool, indicating if the test has been taken
   bool hasTestTaken();
   //  declare a function to record the test score, the parameter will be an integer
   //  use the following rules
   //  -  if no test has been taken, allocate memory and record the score
   //  -  if a test has been taken and the parameter is less than or equal to
   //         the score, do nothing
   //  -  if the test has been taken and the parameter is  higher than the score,
   //         - release the old memory
   //         - allocate new memory
   //         - record the score
   void recordScore(int * myScore);
   //   declare a function to print the score to an ostream parameter
   //   if the test has not been taken, send an appropriate message to the ostream
   //         otherwise print the score
   void printScore(ostream &out);
   //   declare the destructor
   //   be CAREFUL, you will need an if statement in your destructor
   ~testScore();

   private:
   //  declare the data needed to implement the class
   bool testTaken;
   int *score;
 };

//  write the 5 member functions

testScore::testScore() : score(NULL), testTaken(false)
{
    //  declare a default constructor - the pointer should be set to NULL
}

bool testScore::hasTestTaken()
{
   //  declare a function that returns a bool, indicating if the test has been taken
   return testTaken;
}

void testScore::recordScore(int * myScore)
{
   if(testTaken == false)
   {
                score = new int;
                testTaken = true;
                *score = *myScore;
   }
   else if(testTaken == true && *myScore > *score)
   {
                delete score;
                score = new int;
                *score = *myScore;
   }

}

void testScore::printScore(ostream& out)
{
      //   declare a function to print the score to an ostream parameter
   //   if the test has not been taken, send an appropriate message to the ostream
   //         otherwise print the score
     if(testTaken)
     {
                  out << *score << endl;
     }
     else
         out << "The test has not been taken!" << endl;
}

testScore::~testScore()
{
   //   declare the destructor
   //   be CAREFUL, you will need an if statement in your destructor
   if(score != NULL)
   {
             delete score;
   }

}

//  test the class member functions
//    - declare an object, but do NOT record a score for the object

//    - declare a second object and record the scores of 83, 78, 92
//       use appropriate member print functions to verify your code
int main()
{
    int abc = 83;

    testScore firstScore;
    firstScore.printScore(cout);

    testScore secondScore;
    secondScore.recordScore(&abc);
    secondScore.printScore(cout);

    abc = 78;
    secondScore.recordScore(&abc);
    secondScore.printScore(cout);

    abc = 92;
    secondScore.recordScore(&abc);
    secondScore.printScore(cout);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much, I actually learned quite a bit from this, and a few new terms too :)

Comment: *declare a function to record the test score, the parameter will be **an integer***. You declared it to take a pointer to an integer. Reading your question, I suggest you stop, take a breath and reread your material on pointers. If you write `int* myScore = 83;` and need to ask what's wrong about, it means you need to study more.

Comment: Merr, at the beginning she had said: //   declare a class for recording a test score
//   the data will be pointer to an integer, rather than an integer

Comment: That's a requirement for the class, not for the signature of `recordSCore`.

Comment: Okay...
So, if i send it an int instead, and switch around some stuff, I can get it to record the score correctly, but the print function breaks...
Uploading new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that in the default constructor you assign `NULL` to score, so the pointer will point to invalid memory. So, when you call recordStore, when the program comes to this instruction:

```
 *score = *myScore;
```

It leads to a **segmentation fault**, an error which occurs when you try to overwrite a part of memory that your program is not using.

The program will not crash in printScore because reading an invalid pointer is not a error, but it will read garbage data.

EDIT: according to your assignment, the pointer must be allocated in recordStore if the test has not been taken, so in recordStore, change this part:

```
if(testTaken == false)
{
                testTaken = true;
                *score = *myScore;
}
```

to this:

```
if(testTaken == false)
{
                score = new int;
                testTaken = true;
                *score = *myScore;
}
```

Also when you do the `delete` part, you assign first the pointer to NULL, and then delete it; so the program will try to delete the `NULL` pointer (this will not lead to an error), and the memory used for `score` is not released, causing a **memory leak**.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that about the delete thing. Thank you! 
As far as the score thing...
My instructor wants it set to NULL, so I have to :( - But the information you gave on pointers being invalid for null is useful, thank you for that as well! 
But, under recordScore, when it cout's there, it prints correctly...
It is when it gets to printScore it somehow gets changed in the process back to NULL, or maybe just to junk, or to something, I'm not entirely sure. Updating Code

Comment: If you're talking about the Changes section, as you passed an int by value instead of a pointer, a copy of abc will be passed. And that copy will be deleted after the end of the function. So it will be a garbage value later.